# download signed log4j jar

Tags: log4j

Could you please tell me, where to download signed log4j jar,

Answer (score 2):

[Official downloads](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/download.html) include signatures for entire distribution, but inside that the JAR-files are unsigned.

I guess the answer is -- no signed JAR available.

Comment: I am refferring to this link inorder to download the log4j signiture file but I cant "http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/download.html" Any one knows why ??? :|

Comment: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/download.html + https://www.apache.org/dist/logging/log4j/2.7/apache-log4j-2.7-bin.tar.gz.asc -- both work for me.